# Does every mount on FreeBSD need the 10% "root space"?

Tags: linux, unix, freebsd, ufs

So, our servers are being managed by a hosting provider. These servers are running FreeBSD.
Each disk we let them mount loses 10% of it's disk space.

I know (if I understand correctly) that this is normal and the reason is that the file-system allocates 10% diskspace for the root user.
I read for example this: https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/29336/

Now I do understand that the operating systems needs space here and there to do stuff.
However: when we mount a disk under - let's say - /data/web/my-user/some-sub-directory-somewhere-for-a-specific-goal/

Does that mount need to lose that 10% diskspace? Or can/should the hosting provider the `tunefs -m` option in order to save us some money.

Any FreeBSD guru's who can recommend something on this matter?

Comment: The link you provided says that this can be changed and that it is not a loss but a reserve (which is not the same).

Comment: I agree that 10% reserve is not the same as 10% loss. However, if (hypothetically) I have used the remaining 90% of the disk and the file system has been using only 1% of that other reserved 10%, that is a loss of 9%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically that reserved space of 5% (default on Linux) or 10% (on BSD) is used to prevent file system fragmentantion which translates into poor performance when the disk partition or disk drive is used over 95%. I am usually using `tune2fs -m 1 /dev/partition` in order to change the default reserved % to 1% reservation.

If you do know that you are going to use no more than 95% from that disk/partition then you can change the default reserved space to a lower value without an actual impact on the filesysytem's performance

I think this provides a pretty good answer to your question:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7950/reserved-space-for-root-on-a-filesystem-why

It's not related to BSD but to unix/linux but the things are pretty much the same.